# Theos preference loader + tweak error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia, tweak, theos

I am making a cydia tweak with a preference bundle using theos in my iPhone

But I'm getting this error!

[image]

This is the code I have in:

PSListController

(I have no idea where is the error in my code. The code is too long to paste here. I made a link to my codes)
http://pastebin.com/gQvYvB89

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `@proocol UIPopoverControllerDelegate` should be `@protocol UIPopoverControllerDelegate;` (notice the missing "t" and the ending semi-colon)

Comment: Thanks but the same error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but it won't allow me to comment.

A good alternative to IOSOpenDev is Theos, this is more like you are used to as it works the same as on your iphone. You use the make command and have templates.

Installation is fairly involved but here is a good guide.

http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools

Answer (score -1):

You should add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` at the beginning of the header file (this is a common thing: if you encounter a system defined class or protocol - basically every class that starts with NS or UI and some others - you should remove the header generated by class-dump and import the system header, this will save you a lot of headaches).

By the way, you should really NOT compile stuff on device because the GCC that there's on Cydia is very outdated (I think it's from the iOS 3.x days) and using Theos is a pain in the ass anyway: there is another framework that'll help you building preference bundles (and tweaks, siri extensions, toggles for SBSettings, ...), it's called [iOSOpenDev](http://www.iosopendev.com/) and it lets you use Xcode for these projects, which is a MAJOR improvement over compiling on device from the command line (so without code completion, syntax highlighting and all those great improvements Xcode can give you).

PS: if you choose to move to iOSOpenDev feel free to ask for explanations, I have some experience with it ;)

Comment: I tried installing but failed with weird errors. Emailed them but they did not email me back. Although I can see some templates in Xcode when I open Xcode. Compiling them fails

Comment: There was once a bug that caused the install to fail, but should be fixed now: just retry and it should work. In case it doesn't open a new question and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Adding import <UIKit/UIKit.h> didn't help

Comment: Well, I tried it just yesterday! I will start a new topic soon

Comment: From [Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) it looks like `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` has been added in iOS 3.2 and, if I recall correctly, the GCC on Cydia is from iOS 3.0 or 3.1... It could be that: let me check.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the iOS version, but the GCC on Cydia is from 2008 (see the 20080604 in the version number?) so it's definitely outdated... You should really get iOSOpenDev working or at least install Theos on your computer so you can use the latest compiler from Apple.